# Gitignore not ignoring elpa emacs folder

Tags: emacs, gitignore, elpa, melpa

I'm not sure why the gitignore isn't working, but for some reason it continually tries to add the /elpa/ directory to version control. Here is my gitignore (in the root of my dotfiles repository)

```
*.swp
*.swo
*~
\#*\#
/.emacs.desktop
/.emacs.desktop.lock
*.elc
auto-save-list
tramp
.\#*
.org-id-locations
*_archive
*_flymake.*
/eshell/history
/eshell/lastdir
/elpa/
*.rel
/auto/
.cask/
*.last
/elpa/*
/.emacs.d/elpa/*
```

Notice I tried 3 different elpas in here and none of them are working. Does anyone know why?

The directory structure is

```
|- configurations  
 - .gitignore
 |- dotfiles
   |- emacs.d
      | -elpa
      - init.el
      - etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/elpa/` (starting with a '`/`') means it will only ignore the one at the level of the `.gitignore`.
*Not* any `elpa` folder below that `.gitignore` file.

`elpa/` would ignore all `elpa` folders.
(no need for `elpa/*`)

From [`gitignore` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname.
> For example, "`/*.c`" matches "`cat-file.c`" but not "`mozilla-sha1/sha1.c`".